# Inserting records into a SQLite Database isn't actually inserting

Tags: sqlite, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I set up a SQLite Database DB Connection via the CF Admin after installing the JDBC Driver.  After setting it up I got a successful connection message.  I also know that I connected successfully because if I run a simple select query it doesn't fail out and if I run a CFDump it shows the proper columns.  To further test this simple select statement, if I changed the table name it does fail.  So, it's not a connection issue.

I am simply trying to insert records into a table and then check to see if those records were added.  These are the queries I am using:

```
<cfquery datasource="fooDB" name="foo">

        INSERT INTO FooTable
            (FooColumn)
         VALUES
            ('Test')
</cfquery>

<cfquery datasource="fooDB" name="checkIfwasSuccessful">

        SELECT *
        FROM FooTable

</cfquery>
```

This is my SQlite table creator:

```
CREATE TABLE FooTable (
id      INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,  
FooColumn     TEXT,  
OtherColumn1  TEXT,
OtherCOlumn2  TEXT         

);
```

The CFDump of the query `checkIfwasSuccessful` is an empty result.

Any ideas??

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: do you know if you have permissions to the db? it should give you an error, but I have seen stranger things. What happens if you manually insert the record from the db side?

another thought, maybe when you setup the connection, you didn't allow for update access (i would think this would give an error message, but i have never used those limiters in CF, i always do it on the DB side)

Comment: I just checked CF Admin and I did give it update, insert etc. status.  I can insert records into the DB with other programs (Java for example), so all that's left is permissions.  How can I check that I gave it the right permissions?

Comment: Maybe your insert is not being commited for some reason.  try wrapping your insert statement in a cftransaction

Comment: Just tried your suggestion and same outcome... I'm stumped.

Comment: I just started a bounty because this issue is of extremely high importance for me.  Thanks again for your comments.

Comment: Try to analyze the result of the insert query: `<cfquery datasource="fooDB" result="foo">` (`result` instead of `name`), possibly it includes some useful info.

Comment: The output of that are as follows: `CACHED = false` `EXECUTIONTIME = 1` `RECORDCOUNT = 1` and `SQL = INSERT INTO FooTable (FooColumn) VALUES ('Test')`

Comment: BTW, have you tried to open the file with external tool and check if data is there? Possibly problem is in `SELECT`. Related simple guess: have you tried to query as `SELECT FooColumn FROM FooTable`?

Comment: Have you tried doing a select query on data that you haven't inserted with CF?

Comment: Ok, so I found the problem.  The `SELECT` statement I was using appeared in my code twice.  The first time it actually produced a result and the second, which I have been looking at on the `cfdump` this whole time, was running after I had wiped the DB (I first load the DB in question and then copy it elsewhere and then delete the content in the original) .. I think `CFTransaction` may have played a part, but what lead me to find the problem was using the `result` tag on my `SELECT` statement which showed that it was returning results.  So, how do I reward this bounty to the 2 of you?

Comment: I think we would have to post offical answers, but i don't know how to split a bounty.  maybe you should flag your question for moderator help.

Comment: @Limey: your flag is better a question on [meta]

Comment: Please give whole bounty to @Limey once he posts the answer, I feel OK about this. Glad to know that you have solved the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Cftransaction to verify that your query is being commmited.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried either a) supplying an id with the insert, or b) using the AUTOINCREMENT keyword after PRIMARY KEY?

Comment: In SQLite, an integer primary key contains the row id and is filled automatically, so there is not need for autoincrement.